# UICollectionViewController: make sticky footer, regardless of size of CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift3

I am using two supplementary views (i.e., `UICollectionReusableView`s) to render a footer and header that sandwich a UICollectionView.'

The problem is that when the `UICollectionView` is short (Eg, only a single cell is occupied), then the footer view slides up, and does not "stick" to the bottom!

Other articles have addressed this behavior; in some cases, authors use custom-layouts to achieve sticky footers/headers.  Instead, I just set `sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds` and `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds` to `true`, which generally works fine -- until the `UICollectionView` is short.

This happens in Swift 3.0 (iOS 10.3), iPhone 6.x simulator.

What is the recommended approach for pinning a footer view to the bottom of the `UICollectionViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're not stuck on using a UICollectionViewController, I typically use a regular 'ol UIViewController and stick a UICollectionView inside it, extending the UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate protocols.

I suppose if you need the UICollectionViewController, you could do the same thing, but embed the view controller itself.

Using a UIViewController makes it easy to stick views where you want them with constraints.

Comment: We probably will end up following your suggestion.  The reason I chose the "built-in" footer / header with UICollectionViewController is that out-of-the-box, that controller just works nicely for our problem.  I think a generic UIViewController will likely work fine, but may require a little more foot work...

Answer (score 0):

ok.. so I have tried updating code from below link. and it works.

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/add-sticky-footer-to-uicollectionview-in-swift

```
class StickyFooter : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {


var footerIsFound             : Bool = false
var UICollectionAttributes    : [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?


override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}


override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
{
    UICollectionAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

    for  attributes in UICollectionAttributes! {

        if let type = attributes.representedElementKind {

            if type == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter
            {
                footerIsFound = true
                updateFooter(attributes: attributes)
            }
        }
    }

    if (!self.footerIsFound) {

        let newItem = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, at : NSIndexPath(row: self.UICollectionAttributes!.count, section: 0) as IndexPath)


        UICollectionAttributes?.append(newItem!)

    }

    return UICollectionAttributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
{
    let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: elementKind, with: indexPath)

    attributes.size = CGSize(width: self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width, height: 75) //your footer size

    if elementKind.isEqualToString(find: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter)
    {
        updateFooter(attributes: attributes)
    }
    return attributes
}

func updateFooter(attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes){
    let currentBounds = self.collectionView?.bounds
    attributes.zIndex = 1024
    attributes.isHidden = false
    let yOffset = currentBounds!.origin.y + currentBounds!.size.height - attributes.size.height/2.0
    attributes.center = CGPoint(x: currentBounds!.midX, y: yOffset)

}}
```

Comment: assign class StickyFooter to your collectionviewflow layout